# On morphisms to projective space arising from a linear system

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, abelian-varieties, line-bundles, divisors

Context: This question arose as I was reading the proof of Application 6.1 in Mumford's *Abelian Varieties*.  However, I have extracted all of the relevant information below so this question should stand alone.

Let $X$ be a complete variety over an algebraically closed field $k$.  Let $D$ be an effective divisor on $X$ such that the linear system $|D|$ is without basepoints.  (That is, there is no point $P \in X$ such that $P$ is in the support of every divisor on $X$ that is linearly equivalent to $D$.)  Let $L$ be the invertible sheaf associated to the divisor $D$.  Then $|D|$ gives rise to a morphism $\phi : X \to \mathbb{P}^N$, where $N + 1 = \dim \Gamma(X, L)$.  (I will describe this morphism in more detail below.)  If $\phi$ is not a finite morphism, we can find an irreducible curve $C$ in $X$ such that $\phi(C)$ is a single point.  Mumford claims that if $E$ is any effective divisor on $X$ that is linearly equivalent to $D$ then either $E$ contains $C$ or $E$ is disjoint from $C$.  My question is: why is this true?  Why can't $E$ intersect $C$ in a finite set of points?

Construction of $\phi$:
Choose a basis $s_0, \ldots, s_N \in \Gamma(X, L)$.  Let $X_i$ be the set of $x \in X$ such that $s_i \not\in \mathfrak{m}_xL_x$.  Let $U_i = \mathrm{Spec}\,k[y_0, \ldots, \hat{y}_i, \ldots, y_N]$.  Define a ring homomorphism $f_i : k[y_0, \ldots, \hat{y}_i, \ldots, y_N] \to \Gamma(X_i, \mathcal{O}_X)$ by $f(y_j) = s_j/s_i$.  Then by composing the map induced by $f_i$ on spectra with the natural map $\alpha_i : X_i \to \mathrm{Spec}\, \Gamma(X_i, \mathcal{O}_X)$ we obtain $\phi_i : X_i \to \mathrm{Spec}\, k[y_0, \ldots, \hat{y}_i, \ldots, y_N]$.  These maps glue together to define our morphism $\phi : X \to \mathbb{P}^N$.

Small reduction: Changing $\phi$ by an automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^N$ corresponds to choosing a different basis for $\Gamma(X, L)$.  By doing this we may assume that $\phi(C) = [1 : 0 : \cdots : 0]$.  Thus $\phi(C) \in U_0$ and $\phi(C) \not\in U_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq N$.  Thus $C \subset X_0$.  Now, divisors on $X$ give rise to divisors on $X_0$ by restriction, so we can reduce our problem to showing that $C$ is either contained in or disjoint from any divisor of $X_0$ that is linearly equivalent to the restriction of $D$.  The apparent advantage of this (though I haven't been able to make good use of it) is that the map $\phi_0$ is fairly explicit and does not involve glueing morphisms together.

One last comment: We can identify $\mathbb{P}^N$ with $|D_0|$ via $[a_0 : \cdots : a_N] \leftrightarrow \sum_{i = 0}^N a_i (s_i)_0$, where $(s_i)_0$ is the divisor of zeros of the global section $s_i$.  Under this interpretation, $\phi(C)$ is an effective divisor linearly equivalent to $D$.  Perhaps this is a useful way to approach the question?

Comment: Saying that $E$ is linearly equivalent to $D$ means that you can find a hyperplane $H$ in $\mathbb{P}^N$ such that $E = f^*H$. Now, either $H$ contains the point $\phi(C)$, or it doesn't. 

Comment: I mean, $E = \phi^* H$.

Comment: A minor correction regarding your last comment: the $\mathbb P^N$ which is the image of $\phi$ should be identified with the dual of $\lvert D_0\rvert$. Of course, these are both projective spaces of the same dimension, but they are not canonically isomorphic.

Comment: Why is the dual space more appropriate?

Comment: Dear @DustinCartwright can you suggest me a reference where to read in a detailed way about you said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E$ can't intersect $C$ in a finite number of points because otherwise the restriction of $\phi$ to $C$ would be a finite degree morphism, which you assume is not. $E$ is the pull-back of the hyperplane divisor, as Vesselin remarked.

Comment: I am sorry if this is pedantic, but I do not see why the definition of $\phi$ makes $E$ the pull-back of a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^N$. 

Comment: By def, $E$ is lin. eq. to the pull-back of the intersection of an hyperplane with the image of $X$. This is what is - with a little abuse of terminology - known as hyperplane divisor.